# Controllers vs. App-level View in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I'm trying to pick up Backbone.js and one of the issues I'm trying to work through is how people use controllers effectively in Backbone.

I noticed that controllers were added later in the framework, and that views have a significant amount of controller logic just because of the way the browser and DOM are set up. Also the TODO list example on Backbone's website is implemented without a controller.

So I'm just unclear on how to use the controller aspect of backbone. If anyone could shed some light on this topic I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference between a Backbone.View and a Backbone.Controller is that the Controller has the routes architecture, and the corresponding Backbone.History() listener, which pays attention to the part of the URL after the hash tag (#).

Fundamentally, this means that a Backbone.Controller provides bookmarkable URLs.  Because you can hand-write the hash portion, and bookmark them, the Bookmark.Controller should only refer to objects for which it makes sense to display a GETtable item.

I've written a little tutorial, http://www.elfsternberg.com/2010/12/08/backbonejs-introducing-backbone-store/, a port of the Sammy tutorial of The Backbone Store.  If you follow the link to the GitHub repository, you can also get the latest version.

Comment: This is slightly dated now. There are no longer Controllers in Backbone anymore (now called `Router`), and a `View` really performs the functionality of what most expect a Controller to do. The real view is just the dom, update-able with any flavour of DOM lib.

Comment: Yeah, but if you look at the difference, there's barely a name change between "Controller" and "Router," and View was always the primary controller mechanism.  The change clarifies things (you do want to route to bookmarkables, after all), but doesn't mess up the underlying logic at all.